# Could not load type '' (blank) error when trying to reference .NET assembly in NAV2013

Tags: .net, gac, dynamics-nav

I've created an assembly that I want to be able to call from C/SIDE in the Role-Tailored Client in Dynamics NAV2013.

I've got this all working locally but when trying to deploy to the server I can't compile the codeunit that references the .NET assembly

I have a variable of type `DotNet` but when trying to choose a subtype I get this error:

`Could not load type ''` <-- nothing between the single quotes!

I've followed all steps in the MSDN guide (save exporting the types I want to use) I've got this working locally. I can actually get it running by installing the assembly into the GAC, but I don't want to have to do this when it should work otherwise

(the add in is also registered in the `Client Add-in` table and is strong-named with the correct public key token in the table)

These are the things I've tried:

- Building for .NET 4.5, 4 and 3.5 all of which worked locally but not on server
- Dropping the dll in the client and service add-ins folder
- Dropping the dll into windows/system32 folders
- Running everything as administrator (dev environment, service etc etc - I'm logged on as a domain administrator)
- Ripping clumps of my own hair out

All the assembly does is calls out to some webservices and a couple of other things, I just can't work out why I can't get it to work

I suspect it's permission related since installing to GAC seems to make it happy

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be Windows Server 2008R2 security feature which blocks dlls when copied from another machine

I unblocked it and all is well!

Comment: How this feature is called or how to unblock it?

Comment: Right click on the file, choose properties and on the General tab there is a `Unblock` button at the bottom